AG Grid: You are mixing modules (i.e. @ag-grid-community/core) and packages (ag-grid-community)
I'm getting this warning message in my console:

AG Grid: You are mixing modules (i.e. @ag-grid-community/core) and
packages (ag-grid-community) - you can only use one or the other of
these mechanisms.

This warning is the same as was encountered by this user:
Warning in ag-Grid: You are mixing modules (i.e. @ag-grid-community/core) and packages (ag-grid-community)
However, in that case they were installing packages/modules in the same package.json file. My package.json installs ag-grid like this:
"ag-grid-community": "31.3.2",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "31.3.2",
"ag-grid-vue3": "31.3.2",

The imports themselves don't seem to use modules either:
quant@localhost: ~/repo/web_ui $ rg "import.*ag-grid"
src/App.vue
14:import { ModuleRegistry } from "ag-grid-community";

src/components/StoredProcExec.vue
34:import { AgGridVue } from "ag-grid-vue3";

src/components/ServerSideView.vue
37:import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css"; // Mandatory CSS required by the grid
38:import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-balham.css"; // Optional Theme applied to the grid
40:import { AgGridVue } from "ag-grid-vue3";

src/components/StoredProcView.vue
101:import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css"; // Mandatory CSS required by the grid
102:import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-balham.css"; // Optional Theme applied to the grid
106:import { AgGridVue } from "ag-grid-vue3";

src/pages/other/WhoAmI.vue
17:import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css"; // Mandatory CSS required by the grid
18:import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-balham.css"; // Optional Theme applied to the grid
19:import { AgGridVue } from "ag-grid-vue3";

Is this an ag-grid bug?

Although your package.json only contains the Packages installation, you may also be trying to import the Modules part along with the Packages.
If possible, edit the question to show how you are importing the dependencies into your Vue template.

@LucasMarra see edit. I've grep'd for all ag-grid related imports. Does anything stand out to you?

You are seeing this message because you are using the ModuleRegistry which is part of the @ag-grid-community/core Modules.
You can see it on this page of the documentation (use the browser search to find it easier).
I also had this “problem”, I solved it by just removing this code snippet, in the Packages part, there's no need for that.
